# SSRS 2008 R2 need to show all rows from one table even if null - join?

Tags: reporting-services

hoping someone here can help :)

I am working on a report that shows current year's sales and the prior year's sales side by side.  We have 5 different product groups (Construction, Plants, Retail, Seeds and Wholesale) and many product lines under each group (such as "Equipment" under construction, "Herbs" under plants, etc.).

I cannot figure out a way to construct my query so that I can get the groups and product lines to match up side by side going across.  A salesrep may have sold some group/product line this year that he did not sell any $ in prior, and vice versa, he may have had sales in a group/product line in the prior year but not in the current.  So I'm getting rows that aren't matching up because there's no records in one or the other.  I would like to show that group/product line but with $0 sales dollars so the rows line up.  Basically, I am getting order headers for a specific date range, then left outer joining the order details (that actually contains what product group and product line the order is for, not at the header level) and left outer joining the product line desc on the product line id on the order line level.

I've tried left outer join, right and also full, but I only am getting records back where there was at least one order for that product line.  Below is my query; Order is the order header table, Order_Line is the order line table, Customer is the customer table, Major_Grp is the product group table, Category is the product line table, and Salesman is the salesman table:

```
SELECT  ol.PRICE_EXT, c.slsm2_num, s.slsm_desc, ca.pline_desc, m.major_grp_desc
FROM  [ORDER]  o
left outer join [order_line] ol on o.order_num = ol.order_num
left outer join customer c on o.cust_num = c.cust_no 
left outer join salesman s on c.slsm2_num = s.slsm_num
left outer join category ca on ol.pline_Num = ca.pline_Id
left outer join major_grp m on ol.major_grp = m.major_grp
WHERE c.SLSM2_NUM IN (@Salesrep) and 
o.cust_num IN (@CustomerList) and
o.ord_date between (@ReqDateFrom2) and (@ReqDateTo2)
```

what do I have to do to get all Category product lines (and all Major_Grp product groups) to show up regardless if I have any sales for that group/product line?
[image]

thank you SO much in advance for any help! :)

ETA to show an example of what I'm looking to do -- see how now there's rows for Construction and the product line Equipment on the right (Prior) table, but with no sales, and further down the product lines all show and line up, even if no sales.  I need to know how to have every product line for every group have a row, even if no sales for that exist.  See how each row is the same product line?
[image]

here's really what my query looks like (edited it down some to make it easier to follow):

```
SELECT  ol.PRICE_EXT, c.slsm2_num, s.slsm_desc, ca.pline_desc, m.major_grp_desc
FROM  [ORDER]  o
left outer join [order_line] ol on o.order_num = ol.order_num
left outer join customer c on o.cust_num = c.cust_no 
left outer join salesman s on c.slsm2_num = s.slsm_num
right outer join category ca on ol.pline_Num = ca.pline_Id
left outer join major_grp m on ol.major_grp = m.major_grp
WHERE c.SLSM2_NUM IN (@Salesrep) and 
o.cust_num IN (@CustomerList) and
c.comm_flg IN (@CommFlg) and
o.ord_date between (@ReqDateFrom2) and (@ReqDateTo2) and
(ol.prim_vend_num IN (@VendNum) or ol.prim_vend_num is NULL) and
(c.slsm_num IN  (@Salesrep) and ol.major_grp IN ('C', 'R', 'W') or c.slsm2_num IN (@Salesrep)     
and ol.major_grp IN ('P', 'S'))  and
ol.pline_num <> '905' and
ol.pline_num <> '999'
UNION ALL
SELECT  ol.NET_EXT, c.slsm2_num, s.slsm_desc, ca.pline_desc, m.major_grp_desc
FROM  [ORDER_HISTORY]  o
left outer join order_History_line ol on o.order_num = ol.order_num
left outer join customer c on o.cust_num = c.cust_no 
left outer join salesman s on c.slsm2_num = s.slsm_num
right outer join category ca on ol.pline_Num = ca.pline_Id
left outer join major_grp m on ol.major_grp = m.major_grp
WHERE c.SLSM2_NUM IN (@Salesrep) and 
o.cust_num IN (@CustomerList) and
c.comm_flg IN (@CommFlg) and
o.ord_date between (@ReqDateFrom2) and (@ReqDateTo2) and
(ol.prim_vend_num IN (@VendNum) or ol.prim_vend_num is NULL) and
(c.slsm_num IN  (@Salesrep) and ol.major_grp IN ('C', 'R', 'W') or c.slsm2_num IN  (@Salesrep)     
and ol.major_grp IN ('P', 'S'))  and
ol.pline_num <> '905' and
ol.pline_num <> '999'
```

ok, I tried this as well -- making my first table in my query the Category table (which holds all the product lines) and then joining the other tables after that (the example below uses "full join", I tried every join there is with no luck -- and I also tried "ca.pline_Id = ol.pline_num" as well as ol.pline_Num = ca.pline_Id"):

```
SELECT  ol.PRICE_EXT, c.slsm2_num, s.slsm_desc, ca.pline_desc, m.major_grp_desc
FROM  CATEGORY ca
full join major_grp m on ca.major_grp = m.major_grp
full join [order_line] ol on ca.pline_Id = ol.pline_num 
full join [ORDER]  o on ol.order_num = o.order_num
left outer join customer c on o.cust_num = c.cust_no 
left outer join salesman s on c.slsm2_num = s.slsm_num
WHERE c.SLSM2_NUM IN (@Salesrep) and 
o.cust_num IN (@CustomerList) and
c.comm_flg IN (@CommFlg) and
o.ord_date between (@ReqDateFrom) and (@ReqDateTo) and
(ol.prim_vend_num IN (@VendNum) or ol.prim_vend_num is NULL) and
(c.slsm_num IN  (@Salesrep) and ol.major_grp IN ('C', 'R', 'W') or c.slsm2_num IN  (@Salesrep)      
and ol.major_grp IN ('P', 'S'))  and
ol.pline_num <> '905' and
ol.pline_num <> '999'
UNION ALL
SELECT  ol.NET_EXT, c.slsm2_num, s.slsm_desc, ca.pline_desc, m.major_grp_desc
FROM  CATEGORY ca
full join major_grp m on ca.major_grp = m.major_grp
full join [order_history_line] ol on ca.pline_Id = ol.pline_num 
full join [ORDER_HISTORY]  o on ol.order_num = o.order_num
left outer join customer c on o.cust_num = c.cust_no 
left outer join salesman s on c.slsm2_num = s.slsm_num
WHERE c.SLSM2_NUM IN (@Salesrep) and 
o.cust_num IN (@CustomerList) and
c.comm_flg IN (@CommFlg) and
o.ord_date between (@ReqDateFrom) and (@ReqDateTo) and
(ol.prim_vend_num IN (@VendNum) or ol.prim_vend_num is NULL) and
(c.slsm_num IN  (@Salesrep) and ol.major_grp IN ('C', 'R', 'W') or c.slsm2_num IN  (@Salesrep)     
and ol.major_grp IN ('P', 'S'))  and
ol.pline_num <> '905' and
ol.pline_num <> '999'
```

ok, here's what I have working so far.  However, as I said, I get an error on the UNION ALL part of my statement (I tried to BOLD it below, thus the "**" around it -- that's not really in my code!).  Any help?

```
select * from
(select ca.pline_ID, ca.pline_desc, m.major_grp_desc from CATEGORY ca
full join major_grp m on ca.major_grp = m.major_grp) t1
left outer join
(select ol.pline_num, SUM(ol.PRICE_EXT) as SumPriceExt from
[order_line] ol 
full join [ORDER] o on ol.order_num = o.order_num
left outer join customer c on o.cust_num = c.cust_no 
left outer join salesman s on c.slsm2_num = s.slsm_num
where (c.SLSM2_NUM IN (@Salesrep)) and
(c.comm_flg IN (@CommFlg)) and
(o.ord_date between @ReqDateFrom and @ReqDateTo) and
(ol.prim_vend_num IN (@VendNum) or ol.prim_vend_num is NULL) and (c.slsm_num IN (@Salesrep) and      
ol.major_grp IN ('C', 'R', 'W') or c.slsm2_num IN (@Salesrep) and ol.major_grp IN ('P', 'S'))      
and
ol.pline_num <> '905' and
ol.pline_num <> '999'
group by ol.pline_num
) t2 ON t1.pline_ID = t2.pline_num order by t1.MAJOR_GRP_DESC, t1.pline_desc
**UNION ALL**
select * from
(select ca.pline_ID, ca.pline_desc, m.major_grp_desc from CATEGORY ca
full join major_grp m on ca.major_grp = m.major_grp) t1
left outer join
(select ol.pline_num, SUM(ol.Net_EXT) as SumPriceExt from
[order_history_line] ol 
full join [ORDER_history] o on ol.order_num = o.order_num
left outer join customer c on o.cust_num = c.cust_no 
left outer join salesman s on c.slsm2_num = s.slsm_num
where (c.SLSM2_NUM IN (@Salesrep)) and
(c.comm_flg IN (@CommFlg)) and
(o.ord_date between @ReqDateFrom and @ReqDateTo) and
(ol.prim_vend_num IN (@VendNum) or ol.prim_vend_num is NULL) and (c.slsm_num IN (@Salesrep) and      
ol.major_grp IN ('C', 'R', 'W') or c.slsm2_num IN (@Salesrep) and ol.major_grp IN ('P', 'S'))      
and
ol.pline_num <> '905' and
ol.pline_num <> '999'
group by ol.pline_num
) t2 ON t1.pline_ID = t2.pline_num order by t1.MAJOR_GRP_DESC, t1.pline_desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the filter conditions as the join conditions. `WHERE` filters the final result set. That might filter out the records. Try the following query :-

```
SELECT  ol.PRICE_EXT, c.slsm2_num, s.slsm_desc, ca.pline_desc, m.major_grp_desc
FROM  [ORDER]  o
left outer join [order_line] ol on o.order_num = ol.order_num and o.cust_num IN (@CustomerList) and o.ord_date between (@ReqDateFrom2) and (@ReqDateTo2)
left outer join customer c on o.cust_num = c.cust_no and c.SLSM2_NUM IN (@Salesrep)
full outer join salesman s on c.slsm2_num = s.slsm_num
full outer join category ca on ol.pline_Num = ca.pline_Id
full outer join major_grp m on ol.major_grp = m.major_grp
```

Comment: hi!  thanks for the reply -- but I'm not looking to filter out rows, I want to have a row for every product group and product line regarless of if the rep had any sales for a product group/line or not, so the rows will line up.  In other words, I want a row to show in both tables (curr on the left, prior on the right) for every product line we have in our database regardless of if he had sales or not. ?

Comment: I have added full joins, please test and tell me if it works?

Comment: I can try it, but I got an sql syntax error msg when I did the first one.  Also, I tried doing full (and right) outer joins on my original query with no luck :(  I think the issue is that I'm getting my results from the order data first, then linking the prod lines to just the records in the result set.  I don't know how to get ALL the product lines, then go and get all the order info for them?

Comment: ok got the query to work (my actual query has a lot more going on with it -- will post the entire query as an "answer", don't think I can here.  However, I'm still getting the same results, they don't line up.  Can you take a look at my original post?  I added an example of what I need to do -- thanks!  ETA put my actual entire query in my original post...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to join "Group" directly to "ProductLine"? At the Moment you join to them both via the order line table. If the order line table is empty then currently there is no information on which group "Bulbs" belongs to. But the Report you want shows a direct relation that "Bulbs" is in group "Plants", and I guess from the name that "Bulbs" are always in group "Plants", and there should never be an OrderLine with Product "Bulbs" and Group "Construction".

If you can join between ProductLine and Group, then your Group->ProductLine hierarchy for the Report will be fixed, and you can do a left join to the information about orders to get your Sales value.

There may be ways to work around this, but first try to get a direct link between the two tables.

*edit - after joining from Group to Product Line*

OK, the new query is a good start :-)

Now split it up into two bits: one for the Groups and Product Lines (t1 below), and one for the Order Information (t2 below).

Something like

```
select * from
(
select ca.pline_ID, ca.pline_desc, m.major_grp_desc from
CATEGORY ca
full join major_grp m on ca.major_grp = m.major_grp
) t1
left outer join
(
select ol.pline_num, SUM(ol.PRICE_EXT) from
[order_line] ol 
full join [ORDER]  o on ol.order_num = o.order_num
left outer join customer c on o.cust_num = c.cust_no 
left outer join salesman s on c.slsm2_num = s.slsm_num
where c.SLSM2_NUM IN (@Salesrep) 
group by ol.pline_num
) t2
ON t1.pline_ID = t2.pline_num
```

I left out much of the logic for t2, but first try to get it working with a simple t2 for so that all products and Groups are shown, then you can add further conditions and unions as needed.

This is untested, remember you can run the subqueries for t1 and t2 (e.g. select ... m.major_grp) alone to debug them.

Comment: I tried that as well - changed my query to first go to Category (that holds all the product lines) and left outer joined Major_Grp (that holds the product group desc) then went and outer joined the Order (header) and Order_Line (order details) tables, so I think that's what you're suggesting?  And yes, you are correct.  One product line (like "Bulbs") will ONLY be under one product group -- no repetition.  I will update my original question with my current query if you want to look at it.  I'm at my wit's end :(

Comment: Hi @Fillet, I tried the query you suggested but I'm getting the following error:    Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 17
No column name was specified for column 2 of 't2'    -- any ideas?

Comment: ok Fillet, I got it partially figured out.  I had to have an alias for the "sum(Price_Ext) field.  I got that entire query to work, but I need to do a Union All and run the same query against Order/Order_Line's sister tables, Order_History and Order_History_Line, but when I put "UNION ALL" after the last line of the new query (in my first post, above) and copy the same query and change the table names, I get an error because of the UNION ALL statement.  Any help?  thanks!

Comment: I think the Problem is with the order by, the following link might help. If this fails, you can do the sorting in the report. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/10/30/sql-server-union-all-and-order-by-how-to-order-table-separately-while-using-union-all/